# Bootstrap select picker css working but js not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap select picker in my select box. Select box list is dynamic from database. When I change select box then other select box should appear based on previous selection. Its working fine when I didnot implemented select picker js plugin.

After implementation, I can see that selectpicker css is applied but when I click on selectbox then it doesnot expand.

My codes:

```
 function selectstyle()
 {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
 }

 $(document).on("change", "#main_option", function(){
    // to list option in another selectbox
    selectstyle();     //calling selectpicker function.
 }):

 $(document).on("change", "#sub_option", function(){
    // to list option in another selectbox
    selectstyle();     //calling selectpicker function.
 }):
```

Above code is written in document ready and jquery and bootstrap function is loaded at the top of this page. And obiously jquery is at top and first before selectpicker css and js.

Comment: Do you see any JS errors or is it simply not working?

Comment: which technology u are using asp.net ? or .

Comment: Shouldn't `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker()` be initialized on [docReady](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), or at least only initialized only one time? Do you have a fiddle displaying this error?

Comment: Can you open your browsers developer console and tell us the errors you may be receiving?

Comment: I am not getting any error in console.

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twqcp99b/)

I just used `.selectpicker('show');` and `.selectpicker('hide');`